# create multiple triggers in mysql

Tags: mysql

Need to divide all temp values by 10 before inserting.

```
INSERT INTO `gdc_1`(`date`,`time`, `top_die_temp`, `bottom_die_temp`, `side_die_temp`) VALUES ('2021-10-18','23:18','339','356','456')
```

How to create multiple triggers ?

Comment: Why would you need multiple triggers for dividing multiple values in the same row in the same insert operation?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in one trigger as follows:

```
DELIMITER ;;

CREATE TRIGGER t BEFORE INSERT ON gdc_1
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  SET NEW.top_die_temp = NEW.top_die_temp / 10;
  SET NEW.bottom_die_temp = NEW.bottom_die_temp / 10;
  SET NEW.side_die_temp = NEW.side_die_temp / 10;
END;;

DELIMITER ;
```

I don't think you need multiple triggers for this, but for reference you can create multiple triggers per table in MySQL 5.7 or later:

```
DELIMITER ;;

CREATE TRIGGER t1 BEFORE INSERT ON gdc_1
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  SET NEW.top_die_temp = NEW.top_die_temp / 10;
END;;

CREATE TRIGGER t2 BEFORE INSERT ON gdc_1
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  SET NEW.bottom_die_temp = NEW.bottom_die_temp / 10;
END;;

CREATE TRIGGER t3 BEFORE INSERT ON gdc_1
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  SET NEW.side_die_temp = NEW.side_die_temp / 10;
END;;

DELIMITER ;
```

You might choose to use separate triggers if you need to disable one of the actions without changing the others.